# Python list of numbers and returns another list that contains only numbers that appear only once

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numbers, tuples

I try in python 2.7 to to this:
**"Write a program that accepts a list of numbers and returns another list that contains only numbers that appear only once"**
***This is my code***

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,3,6,1,8,9,10,3,50]
list1.sort()
lst = set()
for i in xrange(len(list1)):
    if( int(list1[i]) == int(list1[i+=1]) ):
        continue
    else:
        lst.add(list1[i])

print (lst)
```

*I got this error out-put :*

```
 if( int(list1[i]) == int(list1[i+=1]) ):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: try this `lst=set(list1)`.

Comment: `i+=1` is an assignment *statement* where you need an *expression*. Try `i+1`.

Comment: and why still python 2.7? python 2.7's  [time has run out](https://pythonclock.org/).

Comment: Does this mean "Identify the numbers in the list with mode = 1" or "Produce a list of all numbers present, represented only once"?

Comment: 2.7 Because I'm in college (I don't know why)
The problem is still not resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list in which you will store all number that you already iterated over and check against that list to see if a number has already been inserted:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,3,6,1,8,9,10,3,50]
dups = []
result = []
for elem in list1:
  if not elem in dups:
    result.append(elem)
    dups.append(elem)

print result
```

This will return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 50]
```